# Как эмулировать виртуальное сетевое устройство?

Tags: сеть, локальная-сеть

Как использовать сетевой клиент и сервер на одной машине который используют один и тот же порт для обмена? Возможно ли использовать виртуальное сетевой устройство?

Comment: Может, просто повесьте их на разные IP-адреса? Например, 127.0.0.1 и 127.0.0.2

Comment: Клиент подключается к серверу или тоже работает сервером? Если не работает сервером, то не нужно ничего эмулировать, клиент просто подключается к порту, который слушает сервер.

Comment: Что значит повесить их на разные IP-адреса, как это сделать?

Comment: Клиент открывает X-порт и слушает трафик на нем и сервер открывает тот же X-порт и слушает трафик на нем, это особенность протокола. Когда клиент и сервер на разных машинах с этим проблем нет, но как  разместить их на одной машине?

Comment: Если двум виртуальным loopback-адаптерам назначить разные IP из одной подсети, broadcast-трафик видит только один из адресов в зависимости от того с какого интерфейса он запущен. Возможность получать broadcast-трафик в таком случае тоже часть протокола.